# Synchronizing mouse wheel and MarbleWidget (ZoomIn(), ZoomOut() )

Tags: c++, qt, openstreetmap, kde-plasma

I use `MarbleWidget` with OpenStreetMap on Qt.

Wheel zoom shows blurry images on the map. Therefore, I want to synchronize the mouse wheel with `ZoomIn()` and `ZoomOut()` inorder user to get sharp images on the map.

I want to do something like this:

```
QObject::connect( MarbleWidget, SIGNAL(??????), this, SLOT(wheelEvent(wheelEvent)) ); 

void MainWindow::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event){
    //....
}
```

Is there any signal or event that I can use from MarbleWidget for `???????` above line?

And, how can I disable the mouse zoom on the MarbleWidget?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own input handler and tell `MarbleWidget` to use it. This will allow you to intercept mouse wheel events in the way you are asking.

**Create a custom input handler**

`MarbleWidget` uses a default input handler. Inside of `MarbleInputHandler.cpp` there is a function `eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)` that handles (among other things) the `QEvent::Wheel` event. Derive from this class and override `eventFilter`:

```
class MyMarbleInputHandler : public MarbleWidgetDefaultInputHandler
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyMarbleInputHandler(MarbleWidget* mw) : 
        MarbleWidgetDefaultInputHandler(mw) {}

    virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e);

signals:
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event);
};
```

Basically, you want to intercept `QEvent::Wheel` and emit your own signal. Anything you don't handle yourself should be passed along to the base class.

```
bool MyMarbleInputHandler::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::Wheel)
    {
        emit wheelEvent(static_cast<QWheelEvent*>(e));
        return true;
    }

    return MarbleWidgetDefaultInputHandler::eventFilter(o, e);
}
```

**Create a custom `MarbleWidget`**

The constructor below shows how you can set the input handler defined above. You'll also have to wire the signal/slot.

```
class MyMarbleWidget : public MarbleWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyMarbleWidget()
    {
        MyMarbleInputHandler *myMarbleInputHandler = new MyMarbleInputHandler(this);
        setInputHandler(myMarbleInputHandler);
        connect(myMarbleInputHandler, SIGNAL(wheelEvent(QWheelEvent*)), 
                this, SLOT(handleWheelEvent(QWheelEvent*)));
    }

public slots:
    void handleWheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->delta() > 0) zoomIn();
        else zoomOut();
    }
};
```

`handleWheelEvent()` provides the code to zoom in/out. Not all scroll wheels work the same, so you'll have to figure out how much movement of the mouse wheel it will take to zoom in/out by one step. In this example, it zooms in/out one step based on each event, paying attention only to the sign of `delta()` and ignoring its magnitude.

You might also check out `MarbleDefaultInputHandler::handleWheel()` to see what's going on with the default behavior. They use interpolated/stretched bitmap images between vector layers to provide a smoother animation when zooming. Note that the plus<kbd>+</kbd> and minus<kbd>-</kbd> keys on the keyboard will allow you to zoom to non-interpolated map levels, whereas the mouse wheel zooms using animated ("blurry") interpolated layers. This behavior is [documented in a bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199259).